# In SQL Server is a FAST_FORWARD cursor DYNAMIC by default?

Tags: sql-server, cursors

I've been reading the [DECLARE CURSOR (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) Books Online article.  It states:

> FAST_FORWARD: 
>   Specifies a FORWARD_ONLY, READ_ONLY cursor with performance optimizations enabled.

and

> FORWARD_ONLY:
>   Specifies that the cursor can only be scrolled from the first to the last row. FETCH NEXT is the only supported fetch option. **If FORWARD_ONLY is specified without the STATIC, KEYSET, or DYNAMIC keywords, the cursor operates as a DYNAMIC cursor.**

Does this mean that a FAST_FORWARD cursor is a DYNAMIC cursor by default, unless I also specify that it's STATIC?

Comment: See [Paul's answer here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106454/sp-cursoropen-and-parallelism) and the accompanying link.

Comment: @PaulWhite: Although your answer to the other question answers this one I don't think the two questions are identical.  This one is a specific question about a FAST_FORWARD cursor, the other one is about parallelism and cursors.  Having said that, however, I'm very much a newbie in this forum so I'll leave it you to determine whether it should be marked as a duplicate or not.